# When I use CreateFont() to get the fonts of a string, the arguments are not used

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts

I want to use TrueType Fonts to draw some string onto the screen using OpenGL. But something goes wrong when I try to render them.

The fonts are in incorrect size and position. And the arguments seems not to be used.

Here's the Window I have rendered by using OpenGL:

[image]

These are my codes:

Call the CreateFont func.

```
hFont = CreateFont(10, 0, 0, 0, FW_LIGHT, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_LH_ANGLES, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, L"Consolas");

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
glColor3f(0.1f, 0.45f, 0.75f);
```

I want it to be rendered at the position (0, 0).

```
glRasterPos2f(0, 0);
```

Some Variables.

```
int length = lstrlen(text);
if (length < 1)
    return;
HDC hDC = wglGetCurrentDC();
GLYPHMETRICSFLOAT metric[1];
DWORD dwchar;
int list;
```

Draw each of the fonts.

```
SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    dwchar = text[i];
    list = glGenLists(1);
    wglUseFontOutlines(hDC, dwchar, 1, list, 0.01f, 0.0f, WGL_FONT_POLYGONS, metric);
    glCallList(list);
    glDeleteLists(list, 1);
}

glListBase(list);
DeleteObject(hFont);
```

How should I do next? Everything seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline fonts as drawn by `wglUseFontOutlines` are not affected by raster operation state (glRasterPos) but generate a lot of triangles, which are transformed by the regular transformation matrices. So glTranslate, glScale and so on apply.

Note that:

- wglUseFontOutlines creates a set of display lists for each character. It's inefficient to create and delete display lists all the time. Create them only once, as you need it and then keep them around for drawing.
- display lists are deprecated and have been removed from OpenGL-3 core and later

Comment: So what to do next? How can I draw fonts without drawing lists? I have just got a way to scale the fonts by using glScale3d().

Comment: @PENGUINLIONG: The relationship between text drawing and OpenGL is, well, complicated. Still the most straightforward way is to use a glyph rasterizer in combination with a layout engine to draw into a pixel buffer, load that into a OpenGL texture and draw that using a set of quads. Unfortunately this is the most easy way to go about it.

Comment: Well. I'll try wglUseFontBitmaps. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PENGUINLIONG: wglUseFontBitmaps is not much better. It uses OpenGL's old and deprecated bitmap raster operations. Also it's not portable. I suggest you use freetype-gl, which does what I suggests and packs it into a relatively easy to use interface. Also it's portable. https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a try on it.